# How can I switch chats in Messages with the tab key?

Tags: keyboard, messages

I have gotten a new M1 MacBook Air. On my old MacBook, I could use the tab key to switch from the messages text-entry to the list of chats on the side, then use the arrow keys to move between chats. However, now every time I hit the tab button it just adds a tab into my chat box. I checked through the settings and menus and could not find anything related to this feature. How can I get normal tab-key use back?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/navigate-your-mac-using-full-keyboard-access-mchlc06d1059/mac

Comment: @JBallin I don't want to have to repeatedly enable and disable an accessibility feature, I just want to be able to quickly tab to the chats list which will let me quickly switch between multiple chats.

Comment: You can toggle it using Control-Option-Command-P. I’m guessing you had this enabled on your previous mac.

Comment: @JBallin I have never had that on. My goal is to be able to switch messages quickly, so having to use the complex key combo just to do what used to be a tab->arrow down->tab isn't really a solution.

Comment: Had a chance to look into this more. The setting you likely want is in Keyboard, Shortcuts - check the box at the bottom "Use keyboard...". Agree that the one I suggested is overkill. I use this newer suggestion on all my macs. More detail in linked question.

Comment: @JBallin that does nothing, it is already on and still I just get the tab character in messages. This is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Got it, I've requested to re-open. I see the behavior you're describing in Messages.app on non M1 Macbook too. Possibly the new OS opted to add the "Go to Next Conversation" (control + tab) shortcut instead? I can't verify if tab worked in the past, but this seems like a decent option if you don't mind marking messages as read?

Comment: @JBallin I never realized that was a menu option. I suppose that'll have to do, if not a bit wonky. I'm disappointed it also marks each conversation as read as well. You can put it up as an answer, I don't think what I want is actually possible any more.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this precisely the behavior you were used to but go to:
**System Preferences** > **Accessibility** > **Keyboard** > **Enable Full Keyboard Access**. That should enable you to navigate through elements of the current window. However, I note that if I am in the text box in Messages, I have to <kbd>^ Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to exit input mode and enter into 'UI element navigation' mode.

[image: Screenshot of the Accessibility Keyboard preferences].

To toggle this behavior, **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Keyboard** > **Change the way Tab moves focus**.

[image: Screenshot of the Keyboard preferences]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I can now navigate all of Message's UI elements, but I can only select the message list as a whole, I have no ability to move up or down between chats.

Answer (score 0):

"Go to Next Conversation": <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>.

*Note: Conversations are marked as read.*